# UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: Cannot merge new index 65817 into a non-jumbo instruction

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am facing that problem when I try to build my project on Android Studio. Below is gradle message build:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: Cannot merge new index 65817 into a non-jumbo instruction!
    at com.android.dx.merge.InstructionTransformer.jumboCheck(InstructionTransformer.java:109)
    at com.android.dx.merge.InstructionTransformer.access$800(InstructionTransformer.java:26)
    at com.android.dx.merge.InstructionTransformer$StringVisitor.visit(InstructionTransformer.java:72)
    at com.android.dx.io.CodeReader.callVisit(CodeReader.java:114)
    at com.android.dx.io.CodeReader.visitAll(CodeReader.java:89)
    at com.android.dx.merge.InstructionTransformer.transform(InstructionTransformer.java:49)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.transformCode(DexMerger.java:842)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.transformMethods(DexMerger.java:813)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.transformClassData(DexMerger.java:786)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.transformClassDef(DexMerger.java:682)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:542)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

An here are my dependencies:

```
dependencies {

    // Include and complie all file in libs folder
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.5.0'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.joooonho:selectableroundedimageview:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.newrelic.agent.android:android-agent:5.2.1'
    compile('com.sromku:simple-fb:4.0.5') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
    }
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.photoview:library:1.2.3'
    compile('com.github.manuelpeinado.fadingactionbar:fadingactionbar-abc:3.1.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
    }
    compile('com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:2.+') {
        exclude group: 'com.nineoldandroids'
    }
    compile('com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh:extra-abc:+') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
    }
    compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
    compile(project(':FloatLabel')) {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
        exclude group: 'com.nineoldandroids'
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
}
```

I have found many questions similar this one but those solutions didn't work with me. **How can I resolve this problem?**

Comment: Have you tried enabling multidex ?

Comment: @ShivamVerma I intent to build app for android 2.3, so i didn't enable multidex.

Comment: What made the problem occur? When did it still work, when didn't it? Have you tried cleaning and building again?

Comment: @DaniëlvandenBerg I don't know what is cause this problem. And yes I tried  to clean and rebuild, but still not work.

Comment: I think you can use the multidex support library for android versions < 5.0

Comment: @ShivamVerma thanks for your suggestion, I start woking on it now.

Comment: @ShivamVerma It worked. You could write down your answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @mr.icetea Great! posted it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the multidex support library for android versions below 5.0

Refer : https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#multidex

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible ways to fix your problem:

1. Use [multiDex](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html), but that comes with some drawbacks (see Limitations in the provided link)
2. Configure and use [ProGuard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) to reduce the general footprint of your app. ProGuard will strip unused code from your app and its libraries and might also significantly reduce the size of your apk.